# Change global defaults for .suo contents visual studio 17

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing, xunit

How to set these settings globally, I am using xunit for testing and need to disable this every time I clone the repository for each project.

As I found out this is stored in the .vs folder locally

[image: Change the settings]

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the Visual Studio extensibility (e.g., https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/writing-to-the-user-settings-store?view=vs-2019) to set this programatically as part of your test initialisation.

Comment: I cannot run the test with this option turned on